# Which CSS organization method is fastest?

Tags: html, css, organization, page-load-time

If I have the following HTML:

```
<p id="p1">Paragraph 1</p>
<p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
<p id="p3">Paragraph 3</p>
<p id="p4">Paragraph 4</p>
```

how should I organize the CSS to achieve the fastest page load time?

I could organize it by HTML element, like this:

```
#p1 { font-size:12px; color:red; }
#p2 { font-size:12px; color:blue; }
#p3 { font-size:11px; color:red; }
#p4 { font-size=11px; color:blue; }
```

or by CSS style, like this:

```
#p1, #p2 { font-size: 12px; }
#p3, #p4 { font-size: 11px; }
#p1, #p3 { color:red; }
#p2, #p4 { color:blue; }
```

Which, if either, would be read and processed faster?

**EDIT:** I should have mentioned, I'm working with GreaseMonkey right now, which means two potentially important things:

1) I can't edit any HTML, only CSS

2) All of my CSS is read after the page finishes loading normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, 2nd would certainly be **read** faster since it's smaller.

As far as "processed" goes, by what browser? Unless the style sheet in question deals with tens of thousands of ids I doubt you'd see any significant difference between the two.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how CSS processing would be a bottleneck in page load time. If you want the page to load faster, reduce the size of the HTML/CSS and paste the CSS into a `style` tag in the `head` tag of the HTML. This will avoid an extra GET request, which I'm guessing is the actual source of the slow load time.

Comment: Not necessarily recommended in dynamic pages except maybe for small amounts of CSS, since you'd lose the benefit of caching.  Also not great for reusability.  CSS will almost never be the bottleneck (even as an include) so I'd generally not do this myself.

Comment: Agreed. You _probably_ don't need to optimize the page to the point of putting all CSS in the HTML files.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
.red {color: red}
.blue {color: blue}
.small {font-size: 11}
.big {font-size: 12}
```

And then:

```
<p id="p1" class="big red">Paragraph 1</p>
<p id="p2" class="big blue">Paragraph 2</p>
<p id="p3" class="small red">Paragraph 3</p>
<p id="p4" class="small blue">Paragraph 4</p>
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Its also a neat option but it depends on your markup, sometimes this is worth doing, not always though.

Comment: I'm not particularly fond of your solution, as you are basically including presentation details into the class. What if one day the blue thingie has to appear as green? You will have to modify your css so to say that .blue { color: green; }.

Comment: Stefano, my idea is to separate content from presentation as much as possible. Once an HTML page is ready, I'd rather edit just CSS files from now on.

By the way, sorry for the multiple edits on this answer. Installed FF 3.6b3 and I'm experiencing issues with the markup on this site (the edit icons disappear, lines escape the code markup etc.) Am I the only one?

Comment: I agree with you, but my objection is relative to the css class name, which should express meaning, not presentation.

Comment: Agreed. Obviously, this was just lazy, quick-typing :)

Comment: Also, we don't know what the different paragraphs are supposed to represent, so we don't know enough to name the classes.

Comment: This is a good idea, but, as I should have mentioned, I'm currently writing a GreaseMonkey script, meaning I can't edit the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably profile this in different browsers as they are likely to give you different results.